# Conditions for a G-invariant scheme to be reduced

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a *reduced* and *irreducible* scheme equipped with a $G$-action, where $G$ is a finite group.

> Is there a set of conditions that guarantees $X^G$ is reduced?

*Motivation*: A very simple example of a reduced and *reducible* curve $xy=0$ is provided [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123837/is-the-universal-closed-subscheme-reduced) where under $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action of exchanging coordinates, the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-invariant part $x^2=0$ is *not* reduced.

Comment: What is the scheme structure on $X^G$?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell, $X^G$ is a closed subscheme of $X.$ (actually, in the case I'm interested $X^G$ is a universally closed subscheme of the $G$-Hilbert scheme of $n$ points on $\mathbb{C}^2$.) You may also assume some nice properties, like smoothness if it matters though.